# Text splitting with the regular expressions java

Tags: java, regex

I want to split the text with the help of regex, and then write each word in console from new line. But there is a problem, this `email@mail.org` is not considered as a word and I don't know what regular should be. I try to use look-ahead regex but it didn't help. Should I use the additional if statement to define words or just add something in my regex? 
Code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+[A-Za-z]++");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        while (m.find())
        {
                String s = m.group().replaceAll("\\s++", "");
                System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Comment: So are you just trying to split on whitespace?

Comment: Your regex wont match an email address because you dont allow symbols such as '@'

Comment: Be clear on what you want to do.  It is so confusing after reading your comment in other answers. A good example/test case is a good way to show your intention.

Comment: Show us input text and the output you expect.  I don't recall why I even gave the answer below which I gave, but at this point I don't know what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is to isolate each word from your text and print it out to the console, you can use [`String#split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and split on any amount of whitespace:

```
String[] words = text.split("\\s+");
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

The logic here is focused on the whitespace which separates words, rather than worrying about how each actual word can be matched.

Comment: But in text we have "email@mail.org" or "12th" and it is not a word from the point of view of the English language. I know about split command, but how to remove sequence of letters, which are not words?

Comment: so you don't want `email@mail.org` and `12th` in your result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split on anything that isnt an upper or lowercase letter, for example split on numbers, spaces and symbols you could use:

```
String[] words = "some sentence".split("\\W+");
```

Essentially the reverse of what you were trying to do in your original question by providing a blacklist rather than a whitelist of allowed characters.

If you want to allow scenarios like `email@mail.org` and `12th` and class those as words still, you could just split on a space or some sentence end character

```
String[] words = "some sentence".split("([\\W\\s]*\\s+)");
```

This will split the following:

`email@mail.org x` becomes `email@mail.org` and `x`

`hello world` becomes `hello` and `world`

`hello, world` becomes `hello` and `world`

`hello; world` becomes `hello` and `world`

`hello (world)` becomes `hello` and `world` and  (make sure you filter out empty components)

`hello. World` becomes `hello` and `world`

Comment: I dont want to allow scenarios like email@mail.org and 12th.

Comment: @ИльяШульцев Could you update the question with some sample inputs and outputs for the reg ex please?